# Local Storage or other data persistence in elm

Tags: elm

I am just beginning to look at Elm with the idea of building a simple web application with it. My idea would require to persist some user data in the browser.

Is there a way to handle data persistence directly with Elm? For example in browser session or even local storage? Or should I use ports to do it with JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a look at [TheSeamau5's elm-storage](https://github.com/TheSeamau5/elm-storage). It makes it possible to store data in local storage.

Answer (score 16):

I would suggest to use localStorage. There is no official support for it in the latest elm (by this time it is 0.17), but you can simply do it via ports. This is a working example (based on an example from the offical docs) of using localStorage via ports for elm 0.17

```
port module Main exposing (..)

import Html exposing (Html, button, div, text, br)
import Html.App as App
import Html.Events exposing (onClick)
import String exposing (toInt)

main : Program Never
main = App.program
  {
    init = init
  , view = view
  , update = update
  , subscriptions = subscriptions
  }

type alias Model = Int

init : (Model, Cmd Msg)
init = (0, Cmd.none)

subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model = load Load

type Msg = Increment | Decrement | Save | Doload | Load String

port save : String -> Cmd msg
port load : (String -> msg) -> Sub msg
port doload : () -> Cmd msg

update : Msg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
update msg model =
    case msg of
      Increment ->
        ( model + 1, Cmd.none )
      Decrement ->
        ( model - 1, Cmd.none )
      Save ->
        ( model, save (toString model) )
      Doload ->
        ( model, doload () )
Load value ->
        case toInt value of
          Err msg ->
            ( 0, Cmd.none )
          Ok val ->
            ( val, Cmd.none )

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  div []
    [ button [ onClick Decrement ] [ text "-" ]
    , div [] [ text (toString model) ]
    , button [ onClick Increment ] [ text "+" ]
    , br [] []
    , button [ onClick Save ] [ text "save" ]
    , br [] []
    , button [ onClick Doload ] [ text "load" ]
    ]
```

And the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/elm.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var storageKey = "token";
    var app = Elm.Main.fullscreen();
    app.ports.save.subscribe(function(value) {
      localStorage.setItem(storageKey, value);
    });
    app.ports.doload.subscribe(function() {
      app.ports.load.send(localStorage.getItem(storageKey));
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Now, by pressing buttons +/- you change the int value. When you press "save" button, the app stores the actual value into localStorage (by "token" key). Then try to refresh the page and press "load" button - it takes the value back from localStorage (you should see the HTML text control actualized with the restored value).

Comment: It's probably easier to check `localStorage.getItem(storageKey)` for null and, in case of null, either drop the call to `app.ports.load.send` or pass an empty string.

Answer (score 7):

The official answer is "use ports" (for 0.18 - 0.19.1) while awaiting re-publication of Elm's official local storage library: https://github.com/elm-lang/persistent-cache